# Trace of matrix with power $5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find trace $A^5$ if $A$=$\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 2 & 2} $
I mean to find trace of matrix with any power.  but this matrix has imaginary eigen values

Comment: You matrix is not square...

Comment: r1 is 1 -1 r2 is 2, 2

Comment: row one is 1, -1 row 2 is 2, 2

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues of $A$ are $re^{i\phi},re^{-i\phi}$. So eigenvalues of $A^n$ are $r^ne^{in\phi},r^ne^{-in\phi}$. So $$\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=r^ne^{in\phi}+r^ne^{-in\phi}=2r^n\cos(n\phi)$$

If $f$ is a polynomial and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$.

Comment: very well effort. can you please elaborate a bit more. I mean what you taken r?

Comment: Every complex number can be written in the form $z=re^{i\phi}=r(\cos i\phi+i\sin\phi)$, $r$ is $|z|$. Also note that $\bar z=re^{-i\phi}$ and in this case $z={3\pm\sqrt7i\over2}$ i.e. $r=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that if a matrix is diagonalizable the trace is the sum of his eigenvalues repeated with their algebraic multiplicity. Therefore if $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a eigenvector with $t$ eigenvalue then: $t^n$ is a eigenvalue of $A^n$